# Background image in RWD Theme

Tags: rwd-theme, rwd

I started with the RWD theme to create a resonsive site with our current style.
Except one thing in which I'm running to is the background image...

Before the RWD theme our site had just a static width so it was very easy to put in a background image. But now with the RWD theme the width is completely flexible.

I have already played around a bit with sizes, but I just can't work out how it will looks nice. I want the main part of the shop to have a white background with borders left and right of the site. It would be best if the background is static so it won't scroll down with the user once he starts scrolling.

I really like the idea of the SCSS setup together with compass but I just can't find where to put in the files that the main part of the shop needs to have a white background.

My idea was to put in /content/_home.scss in the body.cms_home tag the background: #FFFFFF tag, but that just won't work.
There are just too many files who all declare some sort of background colour ;)

To get an idea:
My current (just starting) project is located at http://staging.afvallenmetbregje.nl and the current (old) layout of our site is at http://www.afvallenmetbregje.nl

I would really appreciate some input from the more advanced graphic developers on placement / creation of our background....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about magento

Comment: Hi Marius, The RWD Theme is one of the default themes which come pre-installed with Magento. As such I think it does fit in the scope defined in the help center....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, what I did to solve this:

I did create a full size background image without any references to where content would come. Just a full scale picture. 
Afterwards I put in /scss/core/_common.scss in the .main-container, .footer-container a background: #F7D2BE statement to make the background of both containers that specific colour.

This lead to have the background which is of course full page together with the body which is readable by having a light background colour.

Now I need to tidy things up of course and create a good background image instead of this monstrous one.